# Foundation Clearing Lightbox Caption Position

Tags: zurb-foundation

By default, the caption of the ZURB Foundation clearing lightbox is located below the image.

Does anybody know how I can position it above the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the caption to the top with a simple CSS fix. The `bottom` property of the `clearing-caption` class is set to `0` by default. Changing this property to `auto` will move the caption to the top.

```
.clearing-caption {
    bottom: auto
}
```

Comment: You are right - and I'm an idiot for not seeing this (I've got 14 years of web dev on my back... must be blind because I am old.)